# Buck converter output capacitance causing startup issues

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I designed and am testing a buck converter circuit based on the LM5117 IC ([LM5117 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5117.pdf?ts=1632778757587)), which is set to output 10.5V, and is fed with an input voltage of up to 42V. The output of this circuit has two 1000uF capacitors to smooth out the voltage, since it provides power to several peripherals and feeds two other buck converters (to 5V and 3.3V).

This circuit starts up normally when I don't populate the two 1000uF capacitors on PCB, but has issues when they are populated. I suspect this has to do with the current draw at startup being too large, due to capacitors starting at 0 V. If I remove all peripherals, it can usually startup fine even with the capacitors populated since the total current draw at startup is lessened. Although ideally, I would like to be able to turn on and off the entire system without having to remove peripherals each time.

Here is what the buck converter output looks like when it has trouble starting:

[image: Buck converter startup issue]
**5 V/div, 100ms/div**

It looks like it is operating in discontinuous mode, and the voltage stays around 7.5V instead of 10.5V.

I've increased the voltage at which the other buck converters turn on, to prevent the additional current draw at startup, but I am looking for a way to soft-start the system to allow the buck converter a chance to properly start up - or some other solution smarter than that.

Here is the buck converter circuit. I've updated the image to the reflect a full schematic layout since several people said it was not easy to read:

[image: Buck Converter]

In this circuit, the output is set at 9V and it is set to turn on at >= 9.9V on Vcc. The soft startup capacitor is increased to 100n such that the startup time should be 8ms. Two 1000uF capacitors between 9V and GND are also included but not shown since they are in a separate part of the schematic.

Any suggestions for how to solve this issue would be really appreciated!

Comment: If the capacitors are too large, why not reduce their value? You could also increase the value of the soft start cap to make output voltage ramp up slower, reducing current.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire circuit, with values.  If you're running with just the 1000uF caps, and they have substantial ESR, _and_ you have some lead in your compensation network, that could be causing trouble, too.  While you're at it, try to zoom in on one of those vertical jumps in output voltage -- you're showing us what's going on at 100ms/division; show us what happens over a few cycles of the switcher.

Comment: you can place an inrush limiter at the converter output. but as Tim says, zoom in to one of the jumps, as it is not 100% clear what is causing the issue.

Comment: _"it provides power to several peripherals and **feeds two other buck converters**"_ - this may be part of your problem. Do the other buck converters have soft start, or enable inputs that can be used to delay their startup?

Comment: If those further converters have enable signal fed from the same high capacitance line, they may be enabling too slowly causing instability (or if they have no enable pins too). You should try powering the secondary buck converters from lab power supply, with caps and without. Then you'll know if instability comes from your primary buck converter or from capacitors+secondary converters

Comment: @bobflux I want lots of capacitance because I plan to run a brushed DC motor off of the output of the buck converter. I increased the value of the soft start cap so that it takes 80ms to boot up (was previously set at 1.8ms) and this seems to help. I also increased the voltage at which the secondary buck converters turn on at up to ~9V which should allow the 10.5V buck converter a chance to turn on more fully before they start drawing power from it. Thanks!

Comment: @TimWescott I'll post the entire circuit and a more zoomed look at the buck output. I believe this plot was the converter operating in "hiccup mode" and constantly restarting approximately every 60ms.

Comment: Your schematic is unreadable. Might be a correct netlist for your eCAD to produce a layout, but it's bad form. Apart from that, +1 on what bobflux and Bruce says, you need to adjust your softstart to accommodate for your output capacitance and if you have converters downstream, consider (and adjust) their start-up voltage threshold and softstart to match.

Comment: @winny Schematic is optimised for ease of design and accuracy, is pretty standard practice to build schematic layout this way since I'm working from datasheet equations. Full layout with everything connected directly would be a nightmare for design. Image I posted should be enough to find all values and reference them to the datasheet.

I increased soft-start capacitor which seems to have helped, and also increased the voltage at which the downstream converters turn on at to ~8.5V but unfortunately I won't be able to test that part until I get the next iteration of the board.

Comment: Schematic is unreadable. It's usually not a good idea to power a brushed motor from a buck. Why not power it directly from the power supply? (assuming you use PWM to regulate the speed). Note spurious triggering of hiccup mode can be due to a layout problem.

Comment: Schematic is unreadable. It's not even a schematic, it's BOM and netlist together. And luckily it's not standard practice at all. It's all starting from your IC symbol which is not a symbol either, it's package layout with signal names.

Comment: @carloc Why do you say that the IC symbol not a symbol? Yes the pin locations match the package layout, but is there a reason that would make it not considered a symbol?
Also not sure why it would be a BOM, since I haven't included specific parts for almost any of the components.

Comment: @TimWescott I've updated the question to include a schematic layout that should be easier to read, let me know if this is better or not and if there is anything else I should include.

Comment: Much better! How does the situation change if you increase C49 by several times?

Comment: Yes, much better now. I say that's not a symbol meaning it's a poor one instead. There's no reason for following the package layout, in a schematic what we are trying to give is logical signal flow and circuit behaviour. So I'd stick on power supplies on the top edge of the symbol, grounds on th bottom, left inputs, right outputs, with due exceptions following IC typical application circuit. Layout will be addressed later with a different tool, pxb layout, not schematic capture. Two different information, signal flow and connection versus layout, 2 different tools, 2 different ways to do them.